# add a variable to yocto SDK environment setup script

Tags: yocto

How to add a environment variable to yocto SDK environment setup script.

`export CODE_ARGS = "${SAMPLE_ARGS}"`

I want to add this CODE to SDK environment setup script.

Answer (score 0):

These steps might depend on which Yocto release you are using, but the general idea should be the same.

### Steps for Yocto kirkstone:

Looking at the end of the environment setup script you should see something like

```
# Append environment subscripts
if [ -d "$OECORE_TARGET_SYSROOT/environment-setup.d" ]; then
    for envfile in $OECORE_TARGET_SYSROOT/environment-setup.d/*.sh; do
        . $envfile
    done
fi
if [ -d "$OECORE_NATIVE_SYSROOT/environment-setup.d" ]; then
    for envfile in $OECORE_NATIVE_SYSROOT/environment-setup.d/*.sh; do
        . $envfile
    done
fi
```

and e.g. openssl recipe leverages this functionality:

```
do_install:append:class-nativesdk () {
    mkdir -p ${D}${SDKPATHNATIVE}/environment-setup.d
    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/environment.d-openssl.sh ${D}${SDKPATHNATIVE}/environment-setup.d/openssl.sh
    sed 's|/usr/lib/ssl/|/usr/lib/ssl-3/|g' -i ${D}${SDKPATHNATIVE}/environment-setup.d/openssl.sh
}
```

So install shell scripts either under `SDKPATHNATIVE` or `SDKPATH` depending if the variable is used for all targets (`SDKPATHNATIVE`) or for a single target (`SDKPATH`)